# how to save array element as variable in yaml

Tags: yaml

Here is simple construction that is allowing so save specific blocks as variables in yaml:

```yaml
name: &name_val common name
another-name: *name_val
```

If we try to convert into JSON (`yq -p yaml -o json file.yaml`) result will be looks like:

```json
{
  "name": "common name",
  "another-name": "common name"
}
```

What is I'm trying to implement:

Let's say that I have a YAML file:

```yaml
elements:
  - name: common element
    type: common type
    parameters:
      param1: val1
      param2: val2

  - name: common element
    type: common type
    parameters:
      param1: val3
      param2: val4
```

As you can see each element of list is pretty same. And only `parameters` are different.

So I'm trying to set first element as variable and reuse it after, and override only `parameters` block. Something like:

```yaml
elements:
  - &element-object
    name: common element
    type: common type
    parameters:
      param1: val1
      param2: val2

  - *element-object
    parameters:
      param1: val3
      param2: val4
```

But this syntax is not correct, and I can't figure out what is a correct way to implement desired behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I did it. The correct syntax will be:

```yaml
elements:
  - &element-object
    name: common element
    type: common type
    parameters:
      param1: val1
      param2: val2

  - <<: *element-object
    parameters:
      param1: val3
      param2: val4
```

And output of `yq -p yaml -o json file.yaml` will be:

```json
{
  "elements": [
    {
      "name": "common element",
      "type": "common type",
      "parameters": {
        "param1": "val1",
        "param2": "val2"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "common element",
      "type": "common type",
      "parameters": {
        "param1": "val3",
        "param2": "val4"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Where `<<:` is a [merge](https://ktomk.github.io/writing/yaml-anchor-alias-and-merge-key.html) operator